# Apache mod_rewrite: rewrite ^(.*)\.html$ to $1.php and forbid direct access to ^(.*)\.php$

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My intent is to rewrite urls ending in .html to .php (not actually all of them, but that shouldn't really matter with regard to this question). I'd also like to disallow urls ending in .php (so that the user can access every page only using urls with .html extension).

I'm using these rules inside .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

However, this causes a redirection loop. I suppose this happens because the rewritten .html to .php url is fed back to mod_rewrite and causes the first rule to trigger.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That does not make sense. You want to disallow urls ending in .php, but you want to redirect all urls to .html. That is an infinite loop in it's self. Sounds like you need to re-structure your intentions / re-think it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the benefit of doing this is, assuming you only have your link URLs pointing to the `.html` paths, but that aside, you're correct that the rewritten URL is fed back to `mod_rewrite`. This will always happen when using it in a per-directory (`.htaccess`) context, because `mod_rewrite` has to assign itself as the request handler to work correctly in this stage of the Apache request process chain.

Getting to your actual issue, you can solve the problem by conditioning the first rule based upon the original request sent to the server. This could be done like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed. There's actually little benefit in doing this but I am pretty new at Apache and wanted to improve my understanding of mod_rewrite.

Comment: No problem, glad it works for you. Well, that's a pretty good reason itself. `mod_rewrite` is a tricky beast, sometimes.